# Can we use '&&' logic operator inside of the for?

Tags: java, for-loop

Let say we want to see that shape in the output :

```
1
22
333
4444
666666
7777777
88888888
```

Code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for((int i=1;i<=4;) && (int i=6; i<=8;) i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){

            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println();


        }
    }
}
}
```

First question is I don't know how to remove 55555 line to my program's output 
Can somebody help me make the correct corrections with using continue;
Second question is instead of writing continue statement, can we write like this:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {



   **for((int i=1;i<=4;) && (int i=6; i<=8;) i++){**
       for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){

            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm stuck :(

Comment: This syntax is invalid.  What's wrong with just using a nested `if` statement?

Comment: oh actually that was a question from our exam.We were prohibited to use if statement :(

Comment: Will it's a silly exam then :/  (Why would it encourage you to *not* write the most obvious/clear code?)

Comment: ahhahaha well, I think the reason is to check whether we know how to use 'for statement' or not.

Comment: You can't put it in the loop condition or it would end the loop. You can put it in the increment statement (`i = (i == 4 ? 6 : i + 1)`), but there's really no justification for obfuscating your code like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simpler way to do what you are trying to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++){
        if(i != 5) {
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, just write two for loops, the first one running from 1 to 4, and the second one running from 6 to 8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    for(int i = 6; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no - you can't nest loops with a boolean `&&` operator. However, you can use lambdas to implement this

```
IntStream.range(1, 8) // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
    .filter(i -> i != 5) // remove 5
    .forEachOrdered(i -> System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, i)
            .mapToObj(j -> String.valueOf(i)) // repeat i i times
                .collect(Collectors.joining())));
```